# How do we compute $\lim_{x\to c} \tfrac{x}{({1+x})}$ for $c\ne -1$ from the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ defintion?

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to compute $\lim_{x\to c} \tfrac{x}{({1+x})}$ where $c$ is a constant not equal to $-1$.

I started as follows:
$$\left| \frac{x}{1+x} - \frac{c}{1+c} \right| = \left| \frac{x-c}{(1+c)(1+x)}\right|$$
I know that the top can be made smaller than $\delta$, but I'm not sure what to do with the bottom because of the +1 and the fact that we don't know if either of those terms are positive or negative.  Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1+c is fixed, while 1+x can be approximated by 1+c.  Set the $\epsilon,\ \delta$ business accordingly.

Comment: I've tried to clean up your question a little bit.  Note the use of `$$` to display expressions, and the use of `\frac` to make fractions.  If you don't like the edits, please feel free to roll them back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\delta > 0$. Then, for $ c \in \mathbb R \setminus \{-1\}$ it is : $|x-c|<\delta$. Now, it is :

$$\bigg|\frac{x}{1+x} - \frac{c}{1+c}\bigg| = \bigg|\frac{x-c}{(1+x)(1+c)}\bigg| < \frac{\delta}{|(1+x)(1+c)|} = \frac{\delta}{|1+x|\cdot|1+c|}$$

Now, note that from the reverse triangle inequality, you can make that denominator smaller and thus yield a bigger expression, by :

$$1+x = x-c+1+c \Rightarrow |1+x| = |(x-c) - (-1-c)| \geq | |x-c| - |1+c|| =|δ-|1+c||$$

Thus, we get :

$$\bigg|\frac{x}{1+x} - \frac{c}{1+c}\bigg| = \bigg|\frac{x-c}{(1+x)(1+c)}\bigg| < \frac{\delta}{|(1+x)(1+c)|}\leq \frac{\delta}{|\delta-|1+c||\cdot|1+c|} \equiv \varepsilon$$

Summing it up, $\forall \varepsilon>0 \; \exists \delta >0 : |x-c|<\delta \implies \bigg|\frac{x}{1+x} - \frac{c}{1+c}\bigg| < \varepsilon$ and so the limit exists.

Comment: I'm not too sure i understand why the last step follows. Given the $\delta$ at the numerator and denominator, how can we guarantee that the expression will be smaler than $\epsilon$?

Comment: @mmmmo Watch the step above. We just let $\varepsilon$ be the whole expression which was larger than the absolute value which we want to work around.

Comment: yes i think I see now, i just needed to convince myself that the expression could indeed be made as arbitrarily small as one would like, I played around with it and i see why now. Thank you

Comment: @mmmmo $/delta$ can be whatever you want it to be, this the expression can be manipulated ! I'm glad I helped!

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately you want
$$ \left| \frac{x}{1+x} - \frac{c}{1+c}\right| = \left|\frac{x-c}{(1+x)(1+c)}\right| $$ to be small.

Since $c \not= -1$ we can choose an interval centered at $c$ that does not contain $-1$. Let $r = \frac{|c+1|}{2}$. Then $-1 \notin (c-r,c+r)$, and if $x \in (c-r,c+r)$ the reverse triangle inequality gives you $$|x + 1| \ge |c+1| - |x - c| = \frac{|c+1|}{2} = r.$$

This leads to $$\left| \frac{x-c}{(1+x)(1+c)} \right| = \frac{|x-c|}{|1+x| \cdot |1+c|}\le \frac{|x-c|}{\frac r2 \cdot r} = \frac{2}{r^2} |x-c|.$$

Now work on your epsilons and deltas.

Comment: Typo? should be $\frac1{2r^2} |x-c|$?

Comment: Nuts!$\mbox{ }$